Quicksight sorting a legend
I have a stacked bar chart in quicksight which I need to keep the legend sorted in a particular non alphabetic order. The solution that works for me to do this is to prefix each label with a number, for example:
ifelse(
   pets = 'cat', '1.cat',
   pets = 'fish', '2.fish',
   pets = 'dog', '3.dog'
)

But by doing it this way the numbers are displayed in the legend, which is not what I want. Is there a way to add a hidden character to the front of the string which would make the legend sorted in the order I defined without being seen by the user. For example:
ifelse(
   pets = 'cat', '<hidden>1</hidden>cat',
   pets = 'fish', '<hidden>2</hidden>fish',
   pets = 'dog', '<hidden>3</hidden>dog'
)

